# Почему ipa файл такой большой?

Tags: ios, xcode

В xCode создал ipa файл, он сделался 133 мб. Тогда как клон этого приложения для андроид - apk файл весит всего 1,3 мб. Я открыл этот ipa архиватором и увидел вот такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Эти файлы можно удалить? Или как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя удалять эти файлы.

Так как Swift еще очень молодой и довольно быстро меняющийся язык, все необходимые для работы runtime библиотеки запаковываются в "жирный" ipa. Поэтому конечный размер универсального ipa такой большой. После загрузки в App Store Connect, можно посмотреть какой размер загружаемого файла будет для конкретного устройства.

К примеру, экспортированный "жирный" ipa в 200+ Мб:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начиная с Swift 5 + iOS 12.2, установочный размер будет еще меньше.